# Laravel How To Check For Conflict Schedules in An Array

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following array from my query and would like to **check for room schedule clashes.**

```
0 => {#1413 ▼
      +"room": "49"
      +"day": "T-Th"
      +"c_time": "07:00-08:30"
    }
    1 => {#1414 ▼
      +"room": "49"
      +"day": "T"
      +"c_time": "07:00-08:30"
    }
    2 => {#1410 ▼
      +"room": "49"
      +"day": "T-Th"
      +"c_time": "07:00-08:30"
    }
    3 => {#1411 ▼
      +"room": "49"
      +"day": "Th"
      +"c_time": "07:00-08:00"
    }
    4 => {#1433 ▼
      +"room": "51"
      +"day": "M"
      +"c_time": "10:00-11:30"
    }
    5 => {#1409 ▼
      +"room": "49"
      +"day": "M-W"
      +"c_time": "11:30-13:00"
    }
    6 => {#1416 ▼
      +"room": "51"
      +"day": "M-W"
      +"c_time": "1:00-2:30"
    }
```

What I have **tried so far can detect conflicts between single/double day** schedule with the **same time interval and marking them with(bg-red).**

**Like('49','T-Th','7:00-8:30'),('49','Th','7:00-8:30'),('49','T','7:00-8:30')**
**But I would also like to mark schedules with overlapping time interval.**

---

Controller

```
 foreach($subj->get() as $keyG=>$pG) 
            {
              $pGx=explode("-",$pG->day);;
              foreach($pGx as $xKey=>$xx)
              { 
                $classDayTime[]=array('s_id'=>$pG->id,'s_day_time'=>$pGx[$xKey].$pG->c_time.$pG->room);
              }


              
            }
              
            $myarr=array_count_values(array_column($classDayTime,'s_day_time'));
```

---

Blade

```
foreach($subj->paginate(20) as $key=>$p) 
      
        { 
         
         
                ?>
                
                <tr class="
                     <?php 


                $e=explode("-",$p->day);               

                              foreach($e as $dKey=>$d)
                              { 
                                
                                  $dt=$d.$p->c_time.$p->room;
                              foreach($myarr as $ky=>$k)
                            
                              {
                                  if($dt==$ky)
                                  {

                                          if($k != 1)
                                          {
                                            echo "bg-red";  
                                          }
                        
                                          else
                                          
                                          echo " ";  

                                  }     

                              }
                              }
                             
                            ?>
                ">
```

Quite overwhelmed and lost.

**************************************************************************[image: Desired Output]

[image: Problem 1]

---

var_dump($subj)

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection::__set_state(array( 'items' => array ( 0 => (object) array( 'room' => '49', 'day' => 'T-Th', 'c_time' => '07:00-08:30', ), 1 => (object) array( 'room' => '49', 'day' => 'T', 'c_time' => '07:00-08:30', ), 2 => (object) array( 'room' => '49', 'day' => 'T-Th', 'c_time' => '07:00-08:30', ), 3 => (object) array( 'room' => '49', 'day' => 'Th', 'c_time' => '07:00-08:00', ), 4 => (object) array( 'room' => '51', 'day' => 'M', 'c_time' => '10:00-11:30', ), 5 => (object) array( 'room' => '49', 'day' => 'M-W', 'c_time' => '11:30-01:00', ), 6 => (object) array( 'room' => '51', 'day' => 'M-W', 'c_time' => '1:00-2:30', ), 7 => (object) array( 'room' => '39', 'day' => 'W', 'c_time' => '01:00-02:30', ), 8 => (object) array( 'room' => '51', 'day' => 'T-Th', 'c_time' => '4:00-5:30', ), 9 => (object) array( 'room' => '51', 'day' => 'W', 'c_time' => '01:00-02:30', ), 10 => (object) array( 'room' => '49', 'day' => 'T', 'c_time' => '01:00-02:30', ), ), 'escapeWhenCastingToString' => false, ))
```

Comment: Sving you data in a better structure would make it easier to search. Put the start and end time in different properties, and don't store more than one entry per row (means you don't save T-Thu, but instead 3 different rows, one for each of them)

Comment: Restructuring the table is not an option for now.

Comment: You will have to condense your question to a more concrete requirement. `var_export()` of your input data and expected output is a good start.

Comment: Well, I just need how to compare all the time intervals in my array.

Comment: Ok, could you var_export your input array and show us how your expected output would look like?

Comment: Okay. I have uploaded the picture.

Comment: Ok, can you var_export your input array and paste it here?

Comment: That looks like half of it. Can you just dump the var_export() by editing your question?

Comment: Okay, I have already added the var_export

Comment: Nice! I will see if I can come up with something.

Comment: Thanks @nice_dev, hoping you can come up with something. Sorry for my late replies.

Comment: @itsmejoe Can you check the code at this link at your end? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b5cb04251051b18a7b3947092941dc7c13484c1e It basically adds an additional `overlapped` property with `true` or `false` value, so you could easily use this while displaying data in HTML. You can test the code with your datasets and let me know if it fails somewhere.

Comment: @nice_dev it's works like magic. I do not fully understand how it works. But big thanks.

Comment: @itsmejoe Now that you have confirmed it, I will add an answer briefly explaining what's going around.

Comment: Yes. But i did remove['items']since the $data is from the controller queried using get().

Comment: @itsmejoe Ok sure, you can amend the code as you wish in your application. I used `items` since it existed in the var_export().

Comment: Wait.. I did found some problem

Comment: Ok, share a link so I could see

Comment: It will also flag schedules with overlapping time even though its not on the same day.

Comment: Ok, that would make this much easier to solve. But I presume that should only overlap if it's on the same day of the week. Like for example, room bookings in a hotel.

Comment: Yes. kinda like a hotel booking

Comment: Yes, so overlapping time on different days wouldn't make sense. Someone can checkout yesterday and on the next day some other customer can live in that room even though timings match.

Comment: Okay, I think we have misunderstood each other. The problem is T-Th and M-W 7:00-8:30 should not be flagged as overlap.

Comment: I have uploaded another picture.

Comment: Ok, but `T-Th` and `M-W` have an overlap of `7:00-8:30` on Tuesday. By the way, when you say `M-W`, it means Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday or only Monday and Wednesday?

Comment: Only Monday and Wednesday...

Comment: That is where we misunderstood each other. Sorry.

Comment: Its for our school room booking system.

Comment: Ok, never mind. Give me 5 mins. I will amend and share  another link to test. Also, overlaps are only for same days, same room and overlapping time. Correct?

Comment: Yes. same day, same room and and the time

Comment: @itsmejoe Test this and let me know. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e2bd3ff0f3f3836f3fb6d482364ff6bd897541e4

Comment: Yes it works. although it would still flagged schedules with the same end_time and start_time.

Comment: Let's say  a first schedule of the day starts 7:00-8:30 and second schedules starts at 8:30. What should I amend so that it doesn't get flagged as overlap

Comment: Ok great, then just change the if condition to this `$end == -1 || $end <= $time['start'] || $room != $time['room']` and let me know

Comment: Yes!!!Now everything works fine.

Comment: Great.. You could test it with some more and then I would add it as an answer.

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot. BTW could you recommend reading materials or links I can visit. I wanted to improve my php which is obviously at newbie level.

Comment: To be honest, the more apps you develop, the more you will learn about the language. Following any specific tutorials isn't something I would recommend. The [`official site`](https://www.php.net/) is a very good place to refer any methods, functions, it's purpose etc. This question was more on the algorithm side than PHP itself actually.

Comment: Yeah got your point.  My skill  in constructing algorithms is just way off.

Comment: No issues. Every master is a beginner on initial days.

Comment: BTW. This is for my CAPSTONE project would like to acknowledge you. If you want to, I can put your name as one of the contributor.

Comment: @itsmejoe That would be an honour. You can maybe just put a link to my SO profile :-p

Comment: Yeah I can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For every row that has `M-W` or `T-Th` etc, we separate that out into 2 different days and store it in our `$day_map`.
- For every given time, we split the start and end times and convert each of them into seconds.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

function getIntervalTimestamps($t){
    $t = explode("-", $t);
    $f = explode(":", $t[0]);
    $s = explode(":", $t[1]);

    $f = intval($f[0]) * 3600 + intval($f[1]) * 60;
    $s = intval($s[0]) * 3600 + intval($s[1]) * 60;
    if($s < $f) $s += 12 * 3600; 
    return [$f, $s];
}
```

- Now, for every day in our `$day_map`, we sort all the rows by room and their end times in ascending order.
- Now, if any previously given end time is greater than the next row's start time, we say that there is an overlap. If not, we can simply move ahead with our current row.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

usort($day, function($a, $b){
    if($a['room'] != $b['room']) return $a['room'] <=> $b['room'];
    if($a['end'] - $b['end'] == 0) return $a['start'] - $b['start'];
    return $a['end'] <=> $b['end'];
});

$end = -1;
$room = -1;
$prev_key = false;
$overlapped_timings = false;
foreach($day as $time){
    if($end == -1 || $end <= $time['start'] || $room != $time['room']){
        if($overlapped_timings) $data['items'][ $prev_key ]->overlapped = true;
        $prev_key = $time['idx'];
        $end = $time['end'];
        $overlapped_timings = false;
        $room = $time['room'];
    }else{
        $overlapped_timings = true;
        $data['items'][ $prev_key ]->overlapped = true;
        $prev_key = $time['idx'];
        $end = max($end, $time['end']);
    }
}

if($overlapped_timings) $data['items'][ $prev_key ]->overlapped = true;
```

[**Complete Online Demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eab9b3d1cdee4d8ba14023b15987c61cb24cda4e)